# В чем различаются методы использования инициации?

Tags: python

не могу понять разницу использования

```
#!/bin/bash
```

и использования

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

подскажите пожалуйста, уже 3-й час вступоре

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3_(Unix)

Comment: Вообще, в идеале нужно `#!/usr/bin/env python3` использовать, чтобы, например, при использовании виртуального окружения использовался интерпретатор из него, а не системный интерпретатор. См. https://stackoverflow.com/a/19305076/4752653

Comment: @CrazyElf в первом случае файл будет именно интерпретатором bash выполняться, а не через python, это шебанг не для python, а для шелл скриптов

Comment: @insolor А, я думал баш сообразит, что там питон. Ну да, вряд ли. Нет так нет.

Answer (score 2):

Комментарии, начинающиеся с `#!` называются шебанг и показывают, какой программой должен выполнятся файл.

В первом случае вы указываете интерпретатор `bash`, а во втором - `python`.